# Adding Attributes to C# Property set parameter

Tags: c#, attributes, properties

Right now, without using properties, I've got this:

```
public void SetNumber([Array(new int[]{8})] Byte[] number)
```

As you can see, I am adding the `ArrayAttribute` attribute to the parameter.

What I want to do is the same but on a property setter. This doesn't work:

```
[Array(new int[]{8})]
public Byte[] SetNumber
{
  set
  {
  }
  get
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Is there any way of attaching the attribute to the `set_SetNumber` `value` method parameter?

Also, a related question. The two methods generated (the get/set) don't have the custom attribute. Can anyone explain to me why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `param` [attribute target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3787ac0.aspx) on the `set`:

```
public Byte[] SetNumber {
  [param: Array(new int[] { 8 })]
  set {
  }
  get {
    return null;
  }
}
```

As for the second question, the custom attribute is set on the property itself, not on the property accessor methods.

Also, if your `ArrayAttribute` only ever applies to parameters, it could be defined like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class ArrayAttribute : Attribute {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont do that, create a method just as you have done in the first example.  You cant pass anything other than value to the set.

```
public Byte[] TheNumber
{
    private set;
    get
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public void SetNumber([Array(new int[] { 8 })] Byte[] number)
{
    this.TheNumber = number;
}
```

Comment: BTW, if you have an exposed property like above, you can use private set;

Comment: Actually, that might work. Just a bit of background note, I am generating these methods from a XML file. The attribute is for the unit test to generate a proper length array as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but my guess is that you can't do what you want - the setter `value` parameter isn't exposed for you to apply an attribute to.

And as for your second question, a property is distinct from it's getter & setter methods. You can apply an attribute to the setter method like so:

```
public Byte[] SetNumber
{
  [Array(new int[]{8})]
  set
  {
  }
  get
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but I still get null when I try to invoke GetCustomAttribute(true) on the set method version of the Property (in Debug Immediate window). Anyway I think I will give up on the idea for now. Thanks.